# Facebook plugins broken for Chrome?

Tags: facebook, api, google-chrome, social-networking

The [code](http://jsfiddle.net/JWFHE/) is easy :

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<fb:like href="http://www.google.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="auto" show_faces="true" font=""></fb:like>
```

but on Chrome it doesnt works (it doesnt show anythings)... why? And how can I fix this?

Comment: probably you forgot to add `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">` ?

Comment: It shows up in Chrome for me at http://jsfiddle.net/JWFHE/

Comment: Now it works! Yesterday not! :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML5 version of the like code.  I find it's easiest to work with it since I don't have to modify the html tag to include the appropriate XML namespace.

Comment: So I take it that your XML Namespace is properly defined on the HTML tag?

Comment: It doesn't make sense, the jsfiddle works for me on two different machines Chrome browsers.  How many more browsers and how many more machines would I need to try? Also, just because HTML5 is not official, doesn't invalidate the "HTML5" version of the plugin code.  It even works in older IEs too.  So try it and see if it fixes chrome for you, because I cannot find a machine anywhere that is broken.

Comment: I'm on a PC with Chrome version 23.0.1271.97 and it shows up for me  http://jsfiddle.net/JWFHE.